# Right Triangle Trig: Why are the Angles the Same?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

On Khan Academy, the problem involves this picture of a triangle:

[image]

In the problem, we must solve for the theta angle, so in the explanations, the triangle was broken up into a square so that there is the same angle theta on another triangle.

[image]

Here, how do you explain the same angles in this triangle and the one in triangle KGJ? Perhaps an idea being a certain rule of right triangle trig to be followed.

Comment: Corresponding angles

Comment: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_(geometry)#Corresponding_angles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be noted that they are corresponding angles. Under the "Corresponding Angles Axiom", we state that

"When a transversal (here, the line $t$) cuts two parallel lines, then the corresponding angles ($\alpha$ and $\alpha_1$) are equal."

This is an axiom, and can be visually shown by superposition.

[image: Illustration]

In your case, the line through $K$ at $HF$ is parallel to the line $GF$, and line $GH$ is the transversal. Hence, the angles under consideration are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Euclid's geometry states that equal angles are formed by one line such as HG crossing parallel lines such as FG and the horizontal that includes K above it. This means that the angle $\theta$ near $K$ is the same as the angle $\theta$ near G. Since all angles of all three triangle are equal, the triangles are similar.

As for solving, we know that $$HK=\sqrt{5^2+7^2}\approx 8.6$$
$$FG=\frac{7}{5}\times 12=\frac{7+60}{5}\approx 13.4$$
$$HG=\sqrt{12^2+13.4^2}\approx 17.99$$
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}(5/7)\approx 0.62 r\approx 35.54^\circ $$

Answer (score -1):

Call the vertex with $90^{\circ}$ between side lengths $(5,7)$ as $L$. The angle $ HGL$ should not be labelled as $\theta$ already.

The angles $KLF,LFG$ add up to $180^{0},\;. $ So lines $FG,LK$ are parallel.

$LK$ should make the same angle to the transversal cutting line $HKG$ by virtue of parallelism property of ***corresponding*** angles.